# How to deploy a Laravel 5.5 project on cloud hosting (centos 6, Error 404)?

Tags: php, hosting, virtualhost, centos6, laravel-5.5

Here's some server details and what I've done so far:

- Virtual server OS: Centos 6
- No cpanel (of course)
- No public_html folder
- Mysql, apache and php already installed, must say that I ran `yum install httpd` instead of `apache` or `apache2`, is there a difference?
- PHP 7.2.0 installed from that french cool guy remi
- No apache2 folder into etc/

What I've done:

- Uploaded my project into var/ at the same level as www/ via Filezilla
- Created a simbolic link to app/public in www/ with `ln -s var/app/public var/www`
- Set permissions to the app/storage folder with `chmod -R o+w app/storage`
- Uncommented VirtualHost lines into `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and edited DocumentRoot like this: `DocumentRoot var/www/public`

I've been trying different answers from different sites but still can't make my project run on cloud server. When I try to access by IP, I only get the Apache 2 test page "powered by Centos".

**EDIT**
I managed to get it working, and now I can see my login page, but now the problem is that it throws an error 404 when I log in. Do I have to modify .htaccess? Could that be the problem? Not modifying it could be affecting my routes?

Comment: Did you configure apache vhost?

Comment: @Wolen I've edited my question, thanks.